# Is possible to send transactions with blockstream satellite?

Tags: blockstream-satellite

Noob question here. Is it possible to send bitcoin transactions using Blockstream Satellite node or is it used only for receiving blocks?

Comment: Not your question, but you **can** send bitcoin transactions via SMS.  This combined with the satellite download could build a bitcoin system for those without highspeed internet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, communication is unidirectional, you can only receive the data which is broadcast by the system. The satellites [being used](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eutelsat_113_West_A) are TV relays, the uplink essentially being amplified and re-broadcast without any knowledge of the content.Transaction broadcast needs to happen by terrestrial services like a cellphone network, dialup modem, or just the regular internet.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Blockstream satellite as part of a system to conduct transactions, but it can't send transactions on its own.
You can create the entire process of sending and receiving transactions (running a node), without a personal internet connection, by combining the Blockstream satellite hardware to receive blocks, offline wifi for local transactions, and localized mesh networks or SMS for broadcasting.
Excellent breakdown of process here:
https://hackernoon.com/completely-offline-bitcoin-transactions-4e58324637bd

Comment: Hello, @BTC_FTW, that's a nice link, but your post didn't answer the question of the asker, paraphrasing: Can you only receive or also send using the satellite? Any chance you could edit your answer to include an answer to that main question and perhaps a couple sentences of what was great about the linked article?

Comment: Updated. Hope that's better.